# Changing specific Multilist line UIID programmatically

Tags: codenameone

My problem is that layout of my application does not behave in a same manner on different platforms. etc. On Windows platform fonts are larger than on Android or iOS so I'm trying to fix this programmatically.

In case of MultiButton I used:

```
if (platformOS.equals("win")) {    
  findMultiButtonMainMenu1(f).setUIIDLine1("MultiButtonCustom");
}
```

I dont see that MultiList has method for changing specific line UIID.
Is there a way to change UIID of the specific MultiList line programmatically?

Is this the right way to go or I should try to use a different theme when application is running on Windows platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think its very wrong to use code like:

```
if (platformOS.equals("win"))
```

This will litter your code with such hacks. If you want all the OS's to look the same just remove the includeNativeBool from the theme or copy one of the native themes (e.g. the iPhone theme) to get a single look for all platforms.

As to your answer this isn't exposed as an API since the class was mostly designed for the GUI builder but you can call:

```
list.setPropertyValue("uiid1", "YourUIID");
```

To do it.